# When laptop is plugged in, sleep iff the lid is closed, even with external monitors

Tags: macbook-pro, sleep-wake, ventura

My MacBook Pro (16-inch, 2021, M1 Pro) is usually docked, with the lid open and two monitors attached. I would like to use the lid as a physical control for sleep — sleep when it's closed, never sleep when it's open. However, because external monitors are connected, it does not sleep when closed. Is there any way to set it up to behave the way I want?